# Linux net_ratelimit: 12091 callbacks suppressed and Rx status -71

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter

Since Debian Jessie I've got many problems with my Network: The network apapter (an USB 3 One, connected to the USB3 Bus) crashes sometimes the PC or doesn't work anymore with hundreds of kernel messages like:

```
[  850.816365] net_ratelimit: 12091 callbacks suppressed
[  850.816373] r81xx 3-2.3:1.0 eth2: Rx status -71
[  850.816771] r81xx 3-2.3:1.0 eth2: Rx status -71
```

I was already checking about XHCI Endpoint connection problems, but it happens also on USB 2 Port. Thanks in advamce